# Updating Nested JSON Attributes Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to update specific attributes in the JSON data. Those attributes could be anywhere in the nested JSON.

When using OBJECT INSERT using Update statement, the JSON data is getting replaced with the nested object.

Is there any other way to update? If I specify JPATH on the left side of SET command, it is throwing an error.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"id":"1",
                    "name":
                            {"first_name":"ABC",
                             "last_name":"XYZ"},
                    "city_lived":["CITY1","CITY2"],
                    "contacts":
                                {
                                    "phone":
                                        [
                                           {"mob":"45345345"},{"tel":"4363636"}
                                        ],
                                     "email":"abc@xyz.com"
                                  }
                  }')::variant AS VAL
;

UPDATE TEST
SET VAL=OBJECT_INSERT(VAL:contacts,'email','TEST',true);

select * from TEST;

{
  "email": "TEST",
  "phone": [
    {
      "mob": "45345345"
    },
    {
      "tel": "4363636"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have tried and is working but doesn't convince me as a ideal solution. I am open to more suggestions.

Step 1a: Create a Stored Procedure which dynamically generates the keys and jpath.

Use lateral flatten Recursively. For each key capture the JPATH.

Step 1b: Within the procedure Create a Function which captures all the Attributes I wish to update

Create a function which does below,

V. = ""(Default to Empty String)

Step 2: Use the custom function to update the JSON. Reason to dynamically generate a function is because Snowflake Function were not accepting JPATH as argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do something like this :
UPDATE TEST
SET OBJECT_INSERT(VAL, 'contacts', OBJECT_INSERT(VAL:contacts,'email', 'test', TRUE), TRUE)
;